# C++ - Linked List not generating any output

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying a print a linked list. The program is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Link
{
    public:
        int iData;
        double dData;
        Link* pNext;
        Link(int id,double dd)
        {
            iData = id;
            dData = dd;
        }
        void displayLink()
        {
            cout<<"iData = "<<iData<<"\n";
            cout<<"dData = "<<dData<<"\n";
        }
};
class OrderedList
{
    private:
        Link* pRoot;
    public:
        OrderedList()
        {
            pRoot = NULL;
        }
        void insert(int id,double dd)
        {
            Link* newlink = new Link(id,dd);
            Link* pCurrent = pRoot;
            Link* pPrev = pRoot;
            while(pCurrent!=NULL&&pCurrent->iData<=id)
            {
                pPrev = pCurrent;
                pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
            }
                newlink->pNext = pCurrent;
            if(pCurrent==NULL)
            {
                pCurrent = newlink;
            }
            else
            {
                pPrev->pNext = newlink;
            }
        }
        Link* search(int val)
        {
            Link* pCurrent = pRoot;
            while(pCurrent!=NULL&&pCurrent->iData<val)
            {
                pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
            }
            return pCurrent;
        }
        bool remove(int val)
        {
            Link* pCurrent = pRoot;
            Link* pPrev = pRoot;
            while(pCurrent!=NULL&&pCurrent->iData<val)
            {
                pPrev = pCurrent;
                pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
            }
            if(pCurrent==NULL)
                return false;
            else
            {
                Link* temp = pCurrent;
                pPrev->pNext = pCurrent->pNext;
                delete temp;
                return true;
            }
        }
        void displayList()
        {
            Link* pCurrent = pRoot;
            while(pCurrent!=NULL)
            {
                pCurrent->displayLink();
                pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
            }
        }
};
OrderedList ol;
    ol.insert(10,10.10);
    ol.insert(11,11.11);
    ol.insert(12,12.12);
    ol.insert(13,13.13);
    ol.insert(14,14.14);
    ol.insert(15,15.15);
    ol.insert(16,16.16);
    ol.insert(17,17.17);
    ol.insert(18,18.18);
    ol.insert(19,19.19);
    ol.insert(20,20.20);
    ol.insert(21,21.21);
    ol.insert(22,22.22);
    ol.insert(23,23.23);
    ol.insert(24,24.24);
    ol.insert(25,25.25);
    ol.insert(26,26.26);
    ol.insert(27,27.27);
    ol.insert(28,28.28);
    ol.insert(29,29.29);
    ol.displayList();
```

The problem that I am facing is that the code is looking correct and in running fine on paper. When I try to run it on computer, it compiles without any error. However, on executing it, no output is shown. Not even any error. The program just executes without displaying anything. I am not able pin point the problem. I think that the code is fine. Please help me with this problem.

Comment: It looks fine, could you also provide the main that calls the functions? It could be the case that your list is empty...

Comment: It looks considerably less than fine, I'm afraid.

Comment: How does pRoot ever become not NULL?

Comment: insert needs an initial condition when pRoot is still initially NULL.  As it is now, nothing ever gets added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OrderedList` never sets `pRoot` to anything, other than setting it to `NULL` in the constructor. Therefore `insert()` doesn't do anything (other than create a `Link` and leak it), and the call to `displayList()` never enters the `while` loop. `delete()` does no work either, since it always sees an empty list.

Comment: But I am setting `pRoot` to `NULL` only when I create an object of `OrderedList`. After that, when I insert an element, I always create a new object for that. Isn't `pRoot` `NULL` only when the object is created ? Can you please elaborate your answer ?

Comment: `pRoot` is supposed to be the head of the list, right? When you iterate over the list, you start at `pRoot` and go from there. But `pRoot` is always `NULL` -- it never points to anything, so the list is always empty. As @Jim says in the comments on your question, `insert()` needs to handle the case where `pRoot` is null by setting `pRoot` to point to the newly created node.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign pRoot to pCurrent, and make pCurrent point to the new link, this does not update pRoot. When inserting the first node, you will have to update pRoot as well as pCurrent.